# Installing Guest Addition on 12.10 Server

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am encountering a lot of problem trying to install guest additions on Ubuntu 12.10 Server. I have tried many solutions provided in the internet but none of them are working. After mounting the guest additions tools and running `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` it fails.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The errors seem to be because you have a whole bunch of programs missing on your guess. The shell script tries to install the graphical X guest additions (even though you apparently don't have X installed on your server). It also tries to compile the guest kernel modules, but you have neither GCC nor the kernel headers installed, so it fails.

Normally the package manager would automate installing dependencies you need, but a shell script can't do that.

Fortunately, the Guest Additions have been available in the Ubuntu universe repositories for a while. You can install them using from the package `virtualbox-guest-utils` (on the guest). You probably want to skip installing the `virtualbox-guest-x11` package which `virtualbox-guest-utils` recommends, since you don't have X. The necessary compilers, headers, and DKMS stuff should get installed automatically. Be aware that this will use roughly 200 MB of additional disk space.

Answer (score 0):

For compiling the Virtual Box Guest Additions we may need the following packages:

> **dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic**

The build-essentials package will also include the installation of **gcc** needed to compile Guest Additions.

Note however, that the **only** benefit you will have from Guest Additions on a GUI-less server installation is support of USB2.0. Only if you plan to install XServer you may also need the XOrg graphics driver for Virtual Box provided with the Guest Additions.

Comment: I cannot install that, because of similar problems of `gcc`